# updatepanel in a panel controlled by Ajax update control

Tags: c#, html, telerik, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an update panel I need inside of another panel.  This panel is controlled by Ajax update control.  When I have this update panel inside the desired panel, both the update panel and the panel controlled by ajax does not display when pressing the link button.  If I pull this update panel out into its own panel above, both will display, however, it looks a bit tacky and really needs to be inside the ajax controlled panel.

I understand that there is some confliction with how they interact, but not sure how to go about getting desired results.

Comment: Can you show us any code for this?

Comment: I don't have ownership of the code.  The main panel of AllocatedGridPanel is controlled by the RadAjaxManager.  Within this panel though, the client would like to now add an export to excel option which I need in an update panel within the AllocatedGridPanel.  When I click on the AllocatedLinkButton to display the AllocatedGridPanel, nothing shows and I get "Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID'ctl00_DefaultContent_ExcelAllocatedUpdatePanel'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel."